# Accessing Linux from another computer, bypassing firewalls

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, firewall

Is there anything like logmein for Linux, which will automatically bypass firewalls?

edit: Assumed is a corporate firewall which does not allow port forwarding or uPNP. Ideally the solution would provide a "repeater" without me needing to set up an accessible intermediary server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, the whole vnc family (eg. [tightvnc](http://www.tightvnc.com/)):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing

to access your machines through firewalls, you need something like '[nat2nat](http://www.uvnc.com/addons/nat2nat.html)' (you can find related information under the term [stun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN)) or you add constant portforwarding on your router to the machine you want to control.

Comment: Also check UltraVNC (http://www.uvnc.com/)

Comment: if you look at my edit-history of the answer you will see 'uvnc' mentioned. i dropped it coz uvnc is a windows programm ... the nat2nat hint is pointing to uvnc because thats what uvnc uses. to bypass the firewall one needs something similar, and stun is the more general attempt of nat2nat.

Answer (score 0):

Most firewalls allow http traffic on port 80 and 443 or provide a http proxy. You can use this to tunnel through a SSL-VPN like [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) and use any service you like.

In case you only need a console you can use a web terminal like [Serfish](http://www.serfish.com/console/) or install Ajaxterm on your server.

Comment: Ajaxterm on 443.